# Can run liquibase rollback using command line out project path or using spring boot jar without unzip?

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm trying to run liquibase from spring boot jar unzip using maven command to get the liquibase maven plugin

for example

my jar like this xyz.jar and run this jar like this java -jar xyz.jar
now i wont to run liquibase rollback befour run the previous verison for xyz.jar.

Comment: In short, no, not in the automated ways your updates are applied anyway.